# How do I align equations with a column flush right?

Tags: equations

I am using `\documentclass{report}`. I want to have the equation exactly as shown in the image attached.

[image]

This is what I got:

[image]

I have also tried

```
[ Q_k=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} Q_{n}e^{-i(\frac{2\pi kn}{N})}]
  k = 1,2,......,(N-1)
```

Comment: How far have you gotten? What have you tried? Could you edit the relevant part of what you currently have into the question?

Comment: Yes, I have tried. I have problem the part where k=1,2...,(N-1)

Comment: well provide a small complete document that (just) has the equation so far and say what error you got. don't make everyone offering to help type in the whole thing

Comment: you could just use `&k=0,...` to get the side condition,

Comment: You’re new here, but people normally post a Minimal (Non-)Working Example, so we can see what the specific problem is.

Comment: The problem is that when I type that k part, the main equation moves towards the left side of the page. I want the main equation to be at the center and the k part at the right end of the page.

Comment: Sorry, I am new here, I will attach what I got

Comment: Okay. It sounds like you have a document that compiles. Could you post an edited version with only the parts relevant to your question?

Comment: \[ Q_k=\sum_{n=0}^{N-1} Q_{n}e^{-i(\frac{2\pi kn}{N})}\] k = 1,2,......,(N-1)  This is what I have used

Comment: It's good to [edit] the content into the post.  But even better would be to post a complete example.  See https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228

Comment: The second image I attached is what I got with my code

Answer (score 4):

Another solution, with `align*` and the `\mathrlap` command from `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand{\ShowFrameLinethickness}{0.2pt}

\newcommand\upi{\mathrm{i}} % The imaginary constant

\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
Q_k & = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} Q_{n}e^{-\upi\bigl(\tfrac{2\pi kn}{N}\bigr)} \mathrlap{\hskip 4em k = 1,2,\dots,(N-1) }\\
e^{\upi Q} &= \cos Q + \upi \sin Q &
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
Q_k & = \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} Q_{n}e^{-\upi\bigl(\tfrac{2\pi kn}{N}\bigr)} \\
e^{\upi Q} &= \cos Q + \upi \sin Q &
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

If I understand what you want, perhaps this would work:

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\upi{\mathrm{i}} % The imaginary constant

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{flalign*}
& & Q_k &= \sum_{n=0}^{N-1} Q_{n}e^{-\upi (\frac{2\pi kn}{N})} &  \qquad k = 1,2,......,(N-1) \\
& & e^{\upi Q} &= \cos Q + \upi \sin Q &
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

[image: flalign* sample]

This sets the system of equations into columns, spread out across the full width of the page. The first column is empty, the second and third align at the equals signs, and there is some extra space at the start of the last column.  The starred environment suppresses an equation number.

Tweak the definition of `\upi` to how you want the imaginary constant i to appear.  (Your sample seemed to use `\mathrm{i}`.  I personally often use upright italics.  Another common convention is `\i`.)

Answer (score 0):

One way to write the equation set is

```
 \documentclass{report}
 \usepackage{amsmath}

 \begin{document}   
 \begin{align*}
    Q_{k} &= \sum_{n=0}^{(N-1)} Q_{n} \, e^{-i \, \left(\frac{2 \pi k n}{N}\right)} \hspace{10mm} k = 0, 1, \cdots, N-10 \\
    e^{i \, Q} &= \cos{Q} + i \, \sin{Q}
    \end{align*}

 \end{document}
```

Comment: It doesn't work